# Issue in my Dynamic Query

Tags: postgresql

```
select * from pg_tables where schemaname ='reports' and tablename like '%enhancedreports03_0%' order by tablename;
```

> schemaname |           tablename            |     tableowner      | 
>   tablespace  | hasindexes | hasrules | hastriggers
>   ------------+--------------------------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+----------+-------------  reports    | enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01 | ss_agent_summarizer |
>   rpt_data_tbs | t          | f        | f  reports    |
>   enhancedreports03_0_2013_10_08 | ss_agent_summarizer | rpt_data_tbs |
>   t          | f        | f
>
> Check constraints:
>       "enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01_check" CHECK (0::double precision >= date_part('epoch'::text, '1970-01-01'::date) AND 0::double precision < date_part('epoch'::text, '1970-01-02'::date))

I need to drop the constraints in both the tables..So i tried an dynamic query to generate the result set...

```
select 'ALTER TABLE  '||schemaname ||'.'||tablename||' DROP CONSTRAINT '||conname||'' from pg_tables a, pg_constraint b
where schemaname ='reports' and tablename like '%enhancedreports03_0%' and conname like '%enhancedreports03_0_%' order by tablename;
```

> > ### ?column?

```
ALTER TABLE  reports.enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01 DROP CONSTRAINT
 enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01_check  ALTER TABLE 
 reports.enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01 DROP CONSTRAINT
  enhancedreports03_0_2013_10_08_check  ALTER TABLE 
  reports.enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01 DROP CONSTRAINT
  enhancedreports03_0_2013_10_08_check  ALTER TABLE 
  reports.enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01 DROP CONSTRAINT
   enhancedreports03_0_2013_10_08_check  ALTER TABLE 
   reports.enhancedreports03_0_2013_10_08 DROP CONSTRAINT
   enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01_check  ALTER TABLE 
    reports.enhancedreports03_0_2013_10_08 DROP CONSTRAINT
  enhancedreports03_0_2013_10_08_check  ALTER TABLE 
 reports.enhancedreports03_0_2013_10_08 DROP CONSTRAINT
   enhancedreports03_0_2013_10_08_check  ALTER TABLE 
   reports.enhancedreports03_0_2013_10_08 DROP CONSTRAINT
   enhancedreports03_0_2013_10_08_check 
(8 rows)
```

I need the result set to be like this

```
ALTER TABLE  reports.enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01 DROP CONSTRAINT enhancedreports03_0_1970_01_01_check
ALTER TABLE  reports.enhancedreports03_0_2013_10_08 DROP CONSTRAINT enhancedreports03_0_2013_10_08_check
```

Thanks in advance
Abdul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to query `information_schema.table_constraints`  where you can query for table directly instead:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  information_schema.table_constraints 
where 
  table_name like 'enhancedreports03_0_%%' 
order by 
  table_name;
```

The problem with your query is that you are creating cross join because of missing join between `pg_tables` and `pg_constraint`.

Easiest would be to use:

```
select 
    'ALTER TABLE  '||table_schema ||'.'||table_name||
    ' DROP CONSTRAINT '||constraint_name||';' 
from
    information_schema.table_constraints
where
    table_schema ='reports' 
    and table_name like '%enhancedreports03_0%' 
    and constraint_name like '%enhancedreports03_0_%' 
order by
    table_name;
```

[Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-table-constraints.html)

If you would like to use pg catalog, then you have to join tables properly:

```
select
  relname,
  conname
from
  pg_class pcl
  join pg_constraint pco on (pcl.oid = pco.conrelid)
where
  relname like 'enhancedreports03_0_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have check your code in my system it worked absolutely fine and give out put u want so i have add one `;` at the end hope this will help you.

```
select 'ALTER TABLE  '||schemaname ||'.'||tablename||' DROP CONSTRAINT '||conname||';' from pg_tables a, pg_constraint b
where schemaname ='reports' and tablename like '%enhancedreports03_0%' and conname like '%enhancedreports03_0_%' order by tablename;
```